# My data input is 5 GB of numpy arrays, yet running through a function takes 20 GB. Why?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

The code is too complicated to paste here, but I have a numpy array shaped `(800, 800, 1300)`, or 1300 matrices shaped `(800, 800)`. This is 5GB.

I pass this array into a function, whereby the function

1. multiplies each "matrix" in the above array by a float in a `(1300,)` shaped array
2. sums the array into one "matrix", shaped `(800, 800)`
3. and takes the inverse of the matrix

This program runs at 20.2 GB RAM! Is that possible? I cannot see any memory leaks. I am simply taking numpy arrays, and passing them through a function. I then save the resulting arrays.

---

I'll try to post the code.

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
import scipy
import scipy.io
import os

data_file1 = "filename1.npy"
data_file2 = "filename2.npy"
data_file3 = "filename3.npy"

data1 = np.load(data_file1)
data2 = np.load(data_file2)
data3 = np.load(data_file3)

data_total = np.concatenate((data1, data2, data3)) # This array is shape (800,800,1300), around 6 GB. 

array1 = np.arange(1300) + 1

vector = np.arange(800) + 1

def function_matrix(data_total, vector):
    Multi_matrix = array1[:, None, None] * data_total # step 1, multiplies each (800,800) matrix
    Sum_matrix = np.sum(Multi_matrix, axis=0) #sum matrix
    mTCm = np.array([np.dot(vector.T , (np.linalg.solve(Sum_matrix , vector)) )])
    return mTCm

draw_pointsA = np.asarray([[function_matrix(data_total[i], vector[j]) for i in np.arange(0,100)] for j in np.arange(0,100)])

filename = "save_datapoints.npy"

np.save(filename, draw_pointsA)
```

EDIT 2:

See below. It is actually 12 GB RAM, 20.1 GB virtual size of process.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: We can't debug what we can't see. But are you sure it's 20.2 GB of *RAM*? Can you explain exactly how you obtained that measurement?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  It is likely that you are creating intermediate copies of the data while you are working on it.  You will have to provide some code for anybody to answer the question.  If your existing code is too complicated, start removing lines until you can figure out what is essential to recreating the error and provide that.  Taking an inverse of your matrix almost certainly creates some temporary matrices as well.

Comment: Which of the three steps causes the large memory usage?

Comment: 800 * 800 * 1300 * 8 (bytes per float) is 6.7G. The output of ufuncs is a new array.  So step 1 produces a new 6.7G array.  You can reduce this using the `out` parameter.

Comment: RAM or Virtual Memory?  Have you heard of paging?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging

Comment: Narrow down you problem: load data; sleep(100); step 1; sleep(100) .... Check when you get unexpected growth -- right at loading, or during a specific operation?

Comment: wrt. loading, you could store data in a memory-mapped binary file from the start; wrt. processing, try to process in-place, that is avoid copying the matrix, incl. intermediate results.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I am doing this on a remote machine, and I can see how much memory is being used.

Comment: @acdr This is one function call.

Comment: It may be one function call to you, but it's still doing multiple things internally. Use breakpoints or re-write the function, leaving out one step, to see which of the steps causes the increase in memory.

Comment: Right, how can you see how much memory is being used? What tool or command are you using? What results are you seeing? Are you sure that tool measure *RAM* usage and not something else?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz You execute the script remotely via ssh. You type "top". You will see this information listed.   You will see `PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND`

Comment: @ShanZhengYang Right, and you get ... ? Is it the value for `RES` that you're reporting?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I am reporting `VIRT`. 

`PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND`       
`4234 user  20   0 20.1g  12g 2388 R 133.9 82.1  11408:00 python`

Comment: Why? VIRT is not a measure of RAM usage. The RES field is the measure of RAM usage. You are using 12GB of RAM, not 20GB.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz What is VIRT?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz You're right. I'm an idiot.

Comment: VIRT is, more or less, the amount of address space the process is using. And this is a very common mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't answer your question, but proposes a way to avoid the problem from the start.

**Step 1** is sequential -- you only need 1 matrix loaded at a time.
Change your code to process each matrix independently

By **Step 2** your memory requirement is down to `800 * 800 * sizeof(datum)`, which is a few megabytes, and you can certainly afford to keep that in memory.

Comment: So far this is the best approach. It's awkward to do, but it could be done.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this could be a type issue, i.e. you converted the values in the matrices to a different type.  Perhaps you stored the original matrix with values as int16 or a single, and after multiplying it with a float, it's stored as a matrix of double values (which require 2 times more space in memory).

You can use the dtype argument to set the value type for the matrix.

Other possible reasons could be that some additional matrices are created underway.  That's obviously impossible to decode unless you post the code.

A possible solution to your memory problem is to use HDF5 files, and write the matrices to disk. Then you could load the matrix one at a time. This is easy with h5py, as the matrices can be compressed, and/or sliced using numpy/scipy syntax.